# Webpack and toastr

Tags: javascript, webpack, webpack-2, toastr

I am trying to load and bundle toastr as a dependency using webpack.

here is the entire webpack config file

```
var path = require('path');
var ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');
var webpack = require('webpack');

const DEVELOPMENT = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development';
const PRODUCTION = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production';

module.exports = {
    entry: {
        main: './wwwroot/js/mainEntry.js',
        vendor: ['jquery', 'tether',
            'bootstrap', 'jquery-colorbox',
            'jquery-confirm', 'jquery-validation',
            'jquery-validation-unobtrusive',
            'toastr', 'jquery.nicescroll',]
    },
    output: {
        filename: '/js/[name].js',
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'wwwroot'),
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
                    fallback: "style-loader",
                    use: "css-loader"
                })
            },
            {
                test: /\.(ttf|otf|eot|svg|woff(2)?)(\?[a-z0-9]+)?$/,
                loader: 'file-loader?name=[name].[ext]&publicPath=/fonts/&outputPath=/fonts/'
            },
            {
                test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif|ico)$/,
                loader: 'file-loader?name=[name].[ext]&publicPath=/images/&outputPath=/images/'
            }
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
            name: "vendor",
            // (the commons chunk name)
            filename: "/js/vendor.js",
            // (the filename of the commons chunk)
            minChunks: 2,
        }),
        new ExtractTextPlugin({
            filename: 'css/[name].min.css'
        }),
        new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
            $: "jquery",
            jQuery: "jquery"
        })
    ],
};
```

and my entry js file as

```
//JS
import 'jquery-colorbox';
import 'slick-carousel';
import toastr from 'toastr';

//CSS
import './../../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css';
import './../../node_modules/slick-carousel/slick/slick.css';
import './../../node_modules/jquery-colorbox/colorbox.css';
import './../../node_modules/toastr/build/toastr.css';
import './../../node_modules/jquery-confirm/css/jquery-confirm.css';
import './../../node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css';
import './../../Modules/Components/Menu/menu.css';
import './../../wwwroot/css/lahuritv.css';
```

The bundle is created without any errors. And I can see that the toastr script is included in the bundle when I look at the output bundle. But the problem is that the variable `toastr` is not available in the browser window.

I tried looking for similar issue but couldn't find any. This is my first time trying to learn webpack. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Webpack does not expose the modules you import, it bundles your code together with the needed dependencies, but they are still modular and have their own scope. Webpack **does not** just blindly combine the sources of all the files and certainly does not make everything global. If the entry file you posted is the whole file, then you're not doing anything at all.

Instead with webpack you would do the work in the JavaScript files you bundle. So to speak, all you include in your HTML are the bundles created by webpack, you don't include other scripts that try to access something in the bundle, but you rather do it directly in your bundle.

Of course you could expose it to `window` by explicitly defining it: `window.toastr = toastr` after importing `toastr`, but polluting the global scope is generally not a good idea and it's no different from just including `toastr` in a `<script>` tag. If the bundle is just supposed to be used as a library you could have a look at [Authoring Libraries](https://webpack.js.org/guides/author-libraries/). But I think you're just doing a regular web app and you should get all the code together to be bundled by webpack and not rely on it in another `<script>` tag.

You should go through the [Getting Started](https://webpack.js.org/guides/getting-started/) guide of the official docs. The example is very tiny (creates one DOM element) but shows you the concept of webpack apps and also uses an external dependency.

Comment: Thank you for this detailed answer. I think I understand what you mean. The toastr module is only available inside the bundled script and is not exposed as a global variable and anything I need to do with toastr must be done inside the bundle script. But in my case the toastr module is actually needed to be available in the global scope as there is a ASP.NET library that dynamically inserts (server-rendered) a script tag using toastr into the body tag of the view files. So, I guess I will have to use toastr as some kind of external dependecy which is always available at the global scope.

Comment: Correct, that is generally the webpack approach. But if you're converting an old website, which requires globals, to webpack you still have the possibility to expose some of the needed values. But generally you should avoid globals and keep it within the bundle, whenever possible.

Comment: You are right. I am in the middle of converting an old website and in this case I had no option but to expose toastr as a global variable. Thank you for you help. I have resolved this issue now.

Answer (score 8):

Simple solution :

```
//app.js
import toastr from 'toastr'
window.toastr = toastr
```